# C Casting from pointer to uint32_t to a pointer to a union containing uint32_t

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I'd like to know if casting a pointer to uint32_t to a pointer of a union containing a uint32_t will lead to defined behavior in C, i.e.

```
typedef union
{
    uint8_t u8[4];
    uint32_t u32;
} T32;

void change_value(T32 *t32)
{
    t32->u32 = 5678;
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t value = 1234;

    change_value((T32 *)&value); // value is 5678 afterwards

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Is this valid C? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you at least try ??

Comment: @ThibThib UB is hardly detectable by "trying" it.

Comment: I tried and as the comment states, it works perfectly. However, I'm not sure, as casting pointers is sometimes kinda tricky.

Comment: @CastingCrows My answer was incorrect, sorry for the inconvenience. I suggest you accept Jens Gusted's answer instead, so I can delete my - wrong - one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general answer to your question is, no, this is in general not defined. If the union contains a field that has larger alignment than `uint32_t` such a union must have the largest alignment and accessing that pointer would then lead to UB. This could e.g happen if you replace `uint8_t` in your example by `double`.

In your particular case, though, the behavior is well defined. `uint8_t`, if it exists, is most likely nothing other than `unsigned char` and all character types always have the least alignment requirement.

*Edit:*
As R.. mentions in his comments there are other issues with your approach. First, theoretically, `uint8_t` could be different from `unsigned char` if there is an unsigned "extended integer type" of that width. This is very unlikely, I never heard of such an architecture. Second, your approach is subject to aliasing issues, so you should be extremely careful.

Comment: I think there's also an aliasing issue. While when the object in question has union type, the compiler has to be careful about making aliasing assumptions, the opposite is not the case. The existence of a union type, one of whose members matches the type of another object, does not allow aliasing that object.

Comment: Note that if `uint8_t` is defined as `unsigned char`, the aliasing issue is a non-issue. However, `uint8_t` could be defined as an extended integer type with the same range as `unsigned char`. It could even have a different representation (different bit order).

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of incurring downvotes... Conceptually, there is nothing wrong with what you are trying to do.  That is, define a piece of storage that can be viewed as four bytes an a 32 bit integer, and then reference and modify that storage using a pointer.

However, I would ask why you would want to write code where its intent is obscured.  What you are really doing is forcing the next programmer who reads your code to think for minutes and maybe even try a little test program.  Thus, this programming style is "expensive".

You could have just as easily defined, value as:

```
 T32  value;
 // etc.
 change_value(&value);
```

and then avoid the cast and subsequent angst.

Comment: My intention was that change_value can be used for uint32_t as well as for T32. However, considering aliasing issues, it'll probably boil down to the code shown in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Since all union members are guaranteed to start at the same memory address, your program as written does not lead to undefined behavior.